# What's the big O of this little code snippet?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o

```
for i := 1 to n do
  j := 2;
  while j < i do
    j := j^4;
```

I'm really confused when it comes to Big-O notation, so I'd like to know if it's O(n log n). That's my gut, but I can't prove it. I know the while loop is probably faster than log n, but I don't know by how much!

Edit: the caret denotes exponent.

Comment: What does `j^4` do? Is this XOR or exponentiation?

Comment: After `k` steps of the inner loop `j` is strictly greater than `2^k`. So there are at most `log i` inner loop steps, and of course `n` outer loop steps. That's your proof that the op is O(n log n) -- assuming of course that the types involved are the mythical "integers which never overflow, but have constant-time arithmetic operations" ;-). For realistic bigints you'd have to take into account some additional polynomial terms in `log n`, and for realistic fixed-size ints, `j` explodes so quickly that overflow happens for many values of `i`, and `j` gets stuck on 0...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is the number of iterations the while loop is executed for a given `i`.

On every iteration `j:= j^4` and at the beginning `j := 2`, so after `x` iterations `j = 2`<sup>`4^x`</sup>

`j < i` is equivalent to `x < log_4(log_2(i))`

I'd risk a statement, that the complexity is `O(n * log_4(log_2(n)))`

You can get rid of constant factors in Big O notation. `log_4(x) = log(x) / log(4)` and `log(4)` is a constant. Similarly you can change `log_2(x)` to `log(x)`. The complexity can be expressed as `O(n*log(log(n)))`

Comment: +1 I believe this is right. And since big-O notation ignores multiplication by a constant M, this is equivalent to O(n log(log(n)). So the OP is right, the while loop is faster than log(n).

Answer (score 2):

Off the cuff, I'd guess is it is O(*n* slog<sub>4</sub> *n*) where **[slog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Inverse_functions)** represents the inverse of the [tetration operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration). Tetration is the next operation after exponentiation. Just like multiplication is iterated addition, and exponentiation is iterated multiplication, tetration is iterated exponentiation.

My reasoning is, if you multiplied *j* by 4 each iteration then the function would be O(*n* log<sub>4</sub> *n*). But since you are exponentiating it each iteration, you need a correspondingly more powerful operator than log: [slog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Inverse_functions).

Comment: +1 I'm not sure you're right, but it's resourceful reasoning. :-)

Comment: Hm, yeah, thinking about it more this doesn't seem right. But I'll leave the answer up for the educational value! Heh.

Comment: lol, I was thinking that it was (essentially) that operator, too! It's not the answer, but now I know what it's called! (Googling "log of a log of a log" didn't give me much luck. haha